# Can Rhys be played in a mono-green EDH deck?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander, mtg-color-identity

I was wondering if a card with a cost that is either green or white, for example [Rhys the Redeemed](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bRhys%20the%20Redeemed%5d), could be played in a mono-green deck led by a commander such as [Ezuri, Renegade Leader](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bEzuri%2c%20Renegade%20Leader%5d)?

Comment: The question has now been clarified so I have cleared out the comments.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, you cannot play Rhys the Redeemed in a mono-green EDH deck. You can only play cards with hybrid mana costs if all of their colors are part of the commander's color identity.

The [commander rules](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Commander_(format)) describe the color identity rules in rule 903.4:

> The Commander variant uses color identity to determine what cards can be in a deck with a certain commander. The color identity of a card is the color or colors of any mana symbols in that card's mana cost or rules text, plus any colors defined by its characteristic-defining abilities (see rule 604.3) or color indicator (see rule 204).

and the hybrid mana symbols are defined in [rule 107.4e](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Numbers_and_symbols):

> Hybrid mana symbols are also colored mana symbols. Each one represents a cost that can be paid in one of two ways, as represented by the two halves of the symbol. A hybrid symbol such as {W/U} can be paid with either white or blue mana, and a monocolored hybrid symbol such as {2/B} can be paid with either one black mana or two mana of any type. **A hybrid mana symbol is all of its component colors.**

So, Rhys's color identity is green/white, which means that it can only be played in a deck with a commander that has both green and white in its color identity.